# Gridview doesnt populate after deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am designing a web application for my school project that uses C# and web services. A code was given in the school material that i thought would work for my code but it is not showing me results.

This is part of the JSON from the API:

```
{
   "id": 550,
   "overview": "A ticking-time-bomb insomniac and a slippery soap salesman channel primal male aggression into a shocking 

   "title": "Fight Club",
}
```

I am using an api from TMDB to populate the gridview or a listview. I have tried the using the code tht my scl gave and modified it to my requirements. but it isnt working. When I was in debugging mode, i was able to view the json data. but the data doesn't bind to the movielist.

```
public class movies

 {
   public string title { get; set; }
   public string overview { get; set; }
   public int id { get; set; }


 }

public class movielist
{
  public int resultCount;
   public movies[] movielists;
  // public List<movies> movieslists { get; set; } //just tried this
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key={api key}");
    var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string resString = sr.ReadToEnd();//there is JSON here
        movielist list = json.Deserialize<movielist>(resString);// is always null istead of the JSON

        GridView1.DataSource = list.movielists;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
    else
    {
        errortxt.Text = "invalid";
    }
}
```

expected output is for the GridView1 to be populated with the data tht is received. The movielist becomes null instead of populating. There is json in the resString which i am able to open.

Comment: show your full json response rather than just part of it, so its easy to know whats the problem in your code

Answer (score 0):

When the Json deserailizer returns a null it is because the Json doesn't match the model in your code. This could be due to case sensitivity or a few other reasons.

You can fix as follows:

1. Copy the Json text to your clip board.
2. In Visual Studio, go to Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON As Classes.
3. Deserialize using the type in the auto-generated.

Your object should now deserialize correctly.

In general, you should be able to rename the root object of the auto generated class to your liking

However, modifying anything else in the auto-generated code will require using a custom either a [custom deserializer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm) or [attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) to override settings for specific members.